# Calculate number of milliseconds between two times

Tags: java

I'm trying to calculate how many milliseconds between two times (for example between 13:00 to 13:01 there are 60000 milliseconds).
The times are represented by 2 integers (hour, minute).

I wrote this function:

```
public static long millisBetweenTimes(int h1, int m1, int h2, int m2) { //hour1, minute1, hour2, minute2
      long millis;
      millis = (h2 - h1) * (60 * 60000);
      if (m < tm)
        millis += (m2 - m1) * 60000;
      else
        millis -= (m1 - m2) * 60000;
      return millis;
}
```

However, this won't work when the second time is the day after (e.g. how many milliseconds between 14:00 Sunday to 13:00 Monday?)

Comment: How do you know the second time is the day after given that you only got hour and minute?

Comment: This is the heart of your problem: *"The times are represented by 2 integers(hour, minute)"*. The [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package contains pretty much everything you need to work with dates and times, so use that instead.

Comment: You can use the `LocalDateTime.of(...).getNano()` function in the `java.time` for two dates and compute the difference.

Comment: @RickyMo if the second time is before the first time then its the day after. RobbyCornelissen I think that the date classes are very clumsy to use

Comment: @איתןרבינוביץ Now you have stated the condition, you can implement the checking. `if(h2 < h1 || (h2 == h1 && m2 < m1)){ //second time is before firs time } else { //second time is after first time }`

Comment: If you managed to solve the problem, then do not edit your question, but post an answer with your solution.

Comment: Be aware that without a date and a time zone, you cannot account for anomalies such as DayLight Saving (DST) cut-overs when a day is not 24 hours long. A day can be 23, 25, 23.5, or other number of hours long.

Answer (score 10):

As Robby already [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69613390/calculate-number-of-milliseconds-between-two-times/69613583#comment123044940_69613390) in the comments, you should use classes from the `java.time` package. With the classes `LocalTime` and `Duration`, you could get the milliseconds between two points in time.

```java
LocalTime t0 = LocalTime.of(14, 0);
LocalTime t1 = LocalTime.of(13, 0);
Duration d = Duration.between(t0, t1);
if (d.isNegative()) {
    d = d.plusDays(1);
}
System.out.println(d.toMillis());
```

A `Duration` is a, well, duration: the amount of time between two points in time. If the second time lies before the first, then the duration is negative. In such case, we need to add 1 day to the duration.

Now we have an amount of time represented by the `Duration` class. This class contains many methods to convert it to a certain time unit. In our case, `toMillis()` is exactly what we need.

[<kbd>Online demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/jq3y9m)

Instead of `d.isNegative()`, you can also use `t1.isBefore(t0)`, if you think it's more expressive.

---

Note: I think this is not as half as clumsy as doing the math yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach would only work in a single 24 hour cycle as you are passing in two hour integers and subtracting them. So if you are calculating the amount of milliseconds from 13:00 to 14:00 tomorrow the second time input needs to be 25:00 as 24 hours have passed. Another way you can approach this is by using java dates and taking out the hour from the day you want to start and finish.